# Add Draw.io to Github Repo, Errors now Pushing Project Commits

Tags: git, github

To preface, I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to GitHub. I was testing some ideas with flow diagrams from draw.io, and I decided to add the diagrams to my repo. Afterwards, I made some changes to my code and wanted to push a commit and was greeted with the following message:

> Unable to push to the remote repository because your local branch is behind the remote branch. Update your branch by pulling before pushing.

Unfortunately, I cannot do as they request and it will not let me commit my code changes. How should I go about adding external files without affecting my ability to commit my local branch?

Comment: Use `git stash`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that someone (maybe you?) made changes to your remote repo (github) that aren't reflected in your local branch.

One solution:

- save your current work to a spare branch: `git branch work`
- change back to main branch: `git checkout main`
- sync your repo (but not your working directory) to the remote repo: `git fetch --all`
- reset your main branch to the remote main branch: `git reset --hard origin/master`
- merge in your changes: `git merge work`

Once you resolve any conflicts, you can `git push main` to add your changes to the remote repo and also `git branch -d work` to clean up the old work branch.